# Ошибка: Incompatible magic value 791289916 in class file one

Tags: java

Всем привет. Учусь, ничего еще почти не знаю, но ведь все когда-то начинали?

Нашел такой код

файл One.class

```
/* <applet  code="One"  width=200 height=100x/applet>  */ 
import  Java.applet.*; 
import  java.awt.*; 
public  class One extends Applet { 
    public void paint (Graphics g)   { 
        g.drawString (“!!!”,   25,   50);
    } 
}
```

Для запуска One.htm c таким текстом

```
<applet  code="One.class"   width=200   height=100></applet>
```

При запуске появляется ошибка:

> > Incompatible magic value 791289916 in class file one.

В чем причина - почему не работает?

Comment: Все когда начинали. Многие из них уже задавали этот вопрос. Логично сначала воспользоваться поисковой системой.

Comment: УРА УРА УРА!

Я рад как ребенок- установил компилятор и заработало!!

Большое всем спасибо!!!! klopp!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы же не переименовываете паскалевские исходники в exe, и не пытаетесь их так "запустить"? Вот здесь то же самое: сначала one.java должен скомпилироваться в one.class. Делается это при помощи java-компилятора, точно так же, как из паскалевских исходников делается исполняемый файл с помощью компилятора паскаля.

Answer (score 2):

Добрый день. Сразу хочу заметить,что аплеты никто уже давно не использует, поэтому их пропускайте. Затем изучайте Java Core, можно по книгам Философия Java, Основы программирования на Java автаров Хорсман и Корнел. Ну и когда изучите эти книги, определяйтесь с дальнейшим развитием: веб или андроид. Вот такой путь вообщем :-)

Comment: Благодарю!

Comment: > Сразу хочу заметить,что аплеты никто уже давно не использует

ну, я бы не был столь уверенным. В банковском деле и в внутрикорпоративном софте java апплеты живут и процветают. А эта сфера весьма денежная (при правильном внедрении).

Answer (score 2):

Напряг телепатов, вот что они подсказали.

> Incompatible magic value 791289916 in class file one.

791289916 - это 2F2A203C в hex. Разберем по парам - 2F 2A 20 3C - очень похоже на коды символов. Переведем в символы - `/* <`. А это как раз начало собственно java файла. А нормальный скомпилированный class файл начинается с CAFEBABE.

Похоже, что Вы просто переименовали файл вместо компиляции:)

Comment: @KoVadim: По идее, ТС ничего не переименовывал. Он же честно пишет, что java-код — содержимое **файла One.class**. То есть .java и не было в природе.

Comment: вообще он так и назван на старте, но с тем именем тоже ошибка - class.not.found.exception - one.class

Comment: @Allezz: Эээ... Простите, вам что-то говорит слово «компиляция»?

Comment: Я посоветовал бы начать с простого "Hello, World!" с помощью простого текстового редактора и командной строки(терминала). После этого, думаю, многое станет простым и ясным, ну и понятным. :)

Comment: ну... я за 30 минут до вопроса установил jdk&jre, знаю что такое компиляция только по паскалю ;)

Comment: @Allezz: Вот и отлично. В `.class`-файле должен быть не исходник, а результат компиляции. В этом собственно и ваша проблема.

Comment: Спасибо, Vlad.
Итак, я вернул файлу имя one.java и запустил через ком стороку One.htm (в тексте исправил указание на one.java) - получаю ошибку..class.not.found.exception - one.java

Comment: @Allezz: А что, простите, и как вы запустили? Компилятор? Дайте полный лог компиляции тогда.

Comment: Влад, я хочу начать знакомство с Java, установил на комп  jdk&jre, запустил в нотпаде текст и вставил код, случайно нашел в интернете - one.java
Второй файл точно так же сделал - one.html.
То есть оба текста написал не я. Очевидно.
Затем запускаю htm - в Хроме появляется новая закладка и ошибка. Кликаю - появляется сообщение в окне - текст я написал.